# How does a custom type dataset call the groupBy method?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I create a custom type dataset by spark.

```
public class KeyValuePair {
    String source;
    String target;
    int value;
    getter...
    setter...
}
...
List<KeyValuePair> list = generateList();
Dataset<KeyValuePair> dataset = spark.createDataset(list, Encoders.kryo(KeyValuePair.class));
Dataset<Row> agg = dataset.groupBy("source", "target").agg(avg("value"));
```

When the dataset calls the method groupBy, it will throw an exception.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "source" among (value)

I wonder whether a custom type dataset can call the method groupBy. Is Row type dataset the only one can call this method without throw an exception?

How can I aggregate a custom type dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for the exception is: your dataset doesn't have the required columns for aggregation. you can get expected result by using Encoders.bean(class) while creating dataset.

code:

```
 public class DatasetAggregation {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
        List<KeyValuePair> list = generateList();
        Dataset<KeyValuePair> dataset = spark.createDataset(list, Encoders.bean(KeyValuePair.class));
        Dataset<Row> agg = dataset.groupBy("source", "target").agg(avg("value"));
        agg.show();
    }

    public static List<KeyValuePair> generateList() {
        KeyValuePair k = new KeyValuePair();
        k.setSource("a");
        k.setTarget("b");
        k.setValue(10);
        return Arrays.asList(k, k,k);

    }
}

 /* output
 +------+------+----------+
 |source|target|avg(value)|
 +------+------+----------+
 |     a|     b|      10.0|
 +------+------+----------+
*/
```